# How can I find out which process is using which disk?

Tags: disk-usage, 20.10

I have a system with multiple disks loaded by fstab. I set my second disk auto-suspend time to 10min but disk seems to spin forever. Now I need to know which process is accessing that particular disk.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
lsof | grep /mydisk-mount-point
```

Answer (score 0):

Read `man lsof`, and

```
sudo lsof +D /mydisk-mount-point
```